# Vue Toggle Filters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I'm in a rut with some filters I'm trying to make in Vue.

I have an array of colors, an array of objects called products and a property called count to count clicks:

```
data() {
    return {
        count: 0,
        colors: [
            'red',
            'blue',
            'yellow',
            'green'
        ],
        product:[
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Dress shoes',
                price: 5,
                color:'red',
                compare: null
             },
             {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Sports shoes',
                price: 3,
                color:'blue',
                compare: null
             },
             {
                id: 3,
                name: 'Beach shoes',
                price: 2,
                color:'yellow',
                compare: null
             },
             {
                id: 4,
                name: 'Slippers',
                price: 1,
                color:'green',
                compare: null
             }
        ]
    }
}
```

And one filter per color.

```
<button
    class="color-picker"
    v-for="color in colors"
    @click="filterColors(color)">
    {{ color }}
</button>
```

The function that I'm trying to write that filters the colors is:

```
filterColors(color) {
    const filter = event.target || event.srcElement;

    if (product.color !== color) {
        if (this.count % 2 === 1) {
            filter.classList.add("selected");
            product.compare = false;
        }
        if (this.count % 2 === 0) {
            filter.classList.remove("selected");
            product.compare = true;
        }
    }
}
```

So when `compare` is equal to `false`, I add a `hide-me` class to the div that loops through the products and displays them.

With the function above I am able to toggle the class `hide-me` on and off.

When I click on the filter `red` leaves the red items visible and hides all items that are not red. When I click a second time on the filter `red`, it shows all the non-red items that were hidden in the first place, which is what I want.

My problem is that when I hit the filter `red` and hide all items that are not red, I want to e able to hit the filter `blue` and show all the items that are blue keeping the red items visible, and so on fo the rest of the colors.

How can I achieve this with my current code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't need to add any class.

Take a look at this example I've made for you. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-voc8e) it is

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to do this! It's really helpful and cleans up the code so much!

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't do what I need, which is to show only red when clicking red, then when clicking blue show red & blue, when clicking yellow show red & blue & yellow.

Comment: Hi, again. I think [this](https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-zsdj4) will work for you just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to make a computed function which filters your data dynamically and returns it.
You should add a new empty Array where you store your selectedColors and apply that on the computed filter.

Could you provide a jsfiddle for better investigation?

Comment: Thanks for this. The code above is an over simplification of the actual work I'm doing. I'm afraid I have to dig deep within an object with various forEach loops and that object is being brought in by an API call, so I'm not really sure how to get that info into a computed property. Sorry for not providing more details.